# bind9 - forwarders are not working

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I am experiencing an issue with bind. If i want to resolve any domain name that is on the zone file. It works fine. However, when I try to resolve anything that does not belong to the zone file. I know that actual DNS servers that are being forwarded are working fine. But somehow bind9 fails to use them.
The content of /etc/bind/named.conf.options is:

```
options {
directory "/var/cache/bind";
forwarders {
    131.181.127.32;
    131.181.59.48;
};
dnssec-validation auto;
auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

I have also tried to use only one ip address and it still did not work. also the content of /etc/bind/named.conf is:

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
```

So there is no problem with including options file.
Any recommendations for fixing this problem?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I had this issue before with recent version of Bind (9.8.1).

The following option solved the problem for me :

`dnssec-validation no;`

Comment: That solved my problem, but do you know the reason why it does not work when it is auto?

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm using a fake root zone like intra. or local. Are you in the same situation ?

Comment: @profy I also had to do this with my xxxxxx.local forward zone so this may be the issue!

Comment: This worked also for me...I am very curios on the why!

Comment: It is because local created zone are not (and cannot be) signed with dnssec.

Answer (score 2):

You need to differentiate between your bind misconfiguration and not-working forwarders.

You can verify whether the forwarders are working or not using a command like:

```
$ dig @131.181.127.32 www.google.com
```

If you received a valid response, it is a working DNS server and so on.

You may need to add an explicit `allow-recursion` in your bind configuration. It is recommended to restrict this to specific IPs/subnets.

Comment: DNS servers are working. My question is bind9 does not forward any requests to these forwarders.

Comment: Better way is to use dig @nameserver -trace sitename, this will show where the answer is being gotten.

Comment: allow-recursion was the key for me. Thanks.